# Count number of smaller characters to right of particular character in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string, say `txt='string'`. The goal is to count for every character, find the number of smaller characters on right . Hence the output should be;

**Final Output**

`{s:4,t:4,r:3,i:1,n:1,g:0}.` For example, `s` has 4 smaller characters on right; `r,i,n,g`.

I used following code to get number of characters smaller than particular character;

```
arr=[0]*255
txt='string'
for i in range(len(txt)):
    arr[ord(txt[i])]+=1
lst=[idx for idx, element in enumerate(arr) if element==1]
d={}
for j in range(1,255):
     arr[j]+=arr[j-1]
for k in lst:
      d[chr(k)]=arr[k]-1
```

This gives following output; `{'g': 0, 'i': 1, 'n': 2, 'r': 3, 's': 4, 't': 5}`. for example `n` has 2 characters smaller than it in this string; `g,i`. But the question is, how do we know how many of those characters are on the right of `n`. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating things. Try this method:

```py
text = "string"
d = dict.fromkeys(text, 0)
for i, s in enumerate(text):
  for p in text[i:]:
    if p < s:
      d[s] += 1
```

the value of `d` would be:

```
{'s': 4, 't': 4, 'r': 3, 'i': 1, 'n': 1, 'g': 0}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) to understand how `text[i:]` returns the characters after the current one if you don't know the slice notation.

Comment: appreciate your help and showing me a new approach. Will it be possible to do it in linear time, rather than quadratic time as you have shown above.
kindly advise.